# Common information shared between Geopackages

Tags: qgis, database, geopackage

I'm trying to build a map in which I have a few geographical units organized as such.

`Commune ---1:N---> Contrada
Contrada ---1:N---> Vineyards`

One commune may contain many contradas, which in turn may contain many vineyards. On the saide, I also have a list of owners, which may own vineyards spread along many contradas and communes.

What I'd like to do is to have a central producer list and in each vineyard feature, have a metadata field referring to it.

Currently, I have one geopackage file for each commune, using QGIS3. I'm trying to find a way to share this information across geopackages without duplicating that information in each of the communes geopackages, but can't seem to find an easy way.

Or should I just put everything in the same geopackage (at the risk of it getting a bit large) and instead create a geometry-less table in that whole package?

It does seem like the easier solution, but I'm not sure if it will create other challenges down the line.